# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file When trying to run python code in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I try to run Python code in Vs code this appears in the output I have already tried reinstalling both python and Vs code.Ive alos tried other solutions on stackoverflow and none have worked

Comment: Is python in PATH?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried already, so we don't have to go through the same debugging steps that have already failed for you.

Comment: Open Command Prompt and type `python`. What message do you see?

Comment: Why would you expect reinstalling java to make python work? Sounds like you need to install **python**.

Comment: sorry not java i meant python

Comment: When i type python into the command line it says"'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"

Comment: When iclick run python file it works but not when i do it in the output part

Comment: On Windows Python usually installs as `py`.  If that fails, you can try `python3`.

Comment: Go through this [doc](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-python-path) or check this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685) and add your path where python is installed and not same to same as of answer/doc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Comment: When i open vscode i get this. The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing the '"' character. The existence of such a character is known to have caused the Python extension to not load. If the extension fails to load please modify your paths to remove this '"' character.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed python on Windows, you need to add Python command in the PATH variable.

The complete path of python.exe can be added by:

- Right-click *This PC* and go to *Properties*
- Click on the *Advanced system settings* in the menu on the left.
- Click on the *Environment Variables* button o​n the bottom right.
- In the *System variables* section, select the Path variable and click on Edit.

The next screen will show all the directories that are currently a part of the PATH variable. Click on *New* and enter Python’s install directory. Now you can use python directly from the command prompt without having to write its full path location.

Try executing the command `py --version`; it will output the version of Python installed on your system.

Comment: but i want to use python in vs code not in the command prompt

Comment: well, VS Code is a code editor, not a compiler...what it basically does is run your python file in a command prompt...install python, and add it to PATH as suggested above

Comment: how do add it to path?

Comment: my answer explains how to do that